# In Dired, How to disable (or unmap) SPC from executing dired-next-line?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, dired, use-package

**What I want**:

- While in dired, want to disable/unbind `<SPC>` from `dired-next-line`

**Reason:**

- I use `j` or `<C-n>` to `dired-next-line` in dired,
- I never use `<SPC>` as to go next line.
- I use `<SPC>` as leader key, So I want to use my leader key in dired.

**What I've tried so far**: I tried to bind `<SPC>` to `ignore` in `use-package` like following. (with few extra versions haha.)
But still `SPC` executes `dired-next-line`.

```
(use-package dired
  :bind (:map dired-mode-map
              ("<SPC>"    . ignore)
              ("<space>"  . ignore) 
              ("SPC"      . ignore)
              (" "        . ignore)) 
  :ensure nil
  :commands (dired dired-jump)
  :custom ((dired-listing-switches "-agho --group-directories-first"))
  :config
  (evil-collection-define-key 'normal 'dired-mode-map
    "h" 'dired-single-up-directory
    "l" 'dired-single-buffer
    )
)
```

**Update**:

- When I disable `evil-mode`, `<SPC>` no longer executes `dired-next-line` in dired.
- I use `evil` and `evil-collection`. In `evil-collection-dired-setup`,     There is line: `" " 'dired-next-line`. It seems this is the reason.

So far, I don't know how to disable that line defined in `evil-collection-dired-setup`.

Comment: Just bind it to nil in `dired-mode-map`.

Comment: Without `use-package` syntax, that would just be this one-liner: `(define-key dired-mode-map " " nil)`.

Comment: @Drew, you're right. However, I just found the reason it's not working is that I'm using evil and evil-collection. (Somewhere in evil-collection, `SPC` is bind to `dired-next-line` in dired-mode)

Comment: In that case, you'll help yourself get an answer by adding the tag `evil`. I've done that for you. Hope you get a good answer (I don't use Evil).

Comment: @Drew, Thanks mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haha, The solution was in plain sight all along:

As written in the **update** section, `<SPC>` needed to unbind (or disabled) at `evil-collection`'s `'normal` state + `dired-mode`. So the config is:

```
(use-package dired
  :ensure nil
  :commands (dired dired-jump)
  :custom ((dired-listing-switches "-agho --group-directories-first"))
  :config
  (evil-collection-define-key 'normal 'dired-mode-map
    "h" 'dired-single-up-directory   # <=====
    "l" 'dired-single-buffer         # <=====
    " " 'nil                         # <=====  this line
    ))
```

So basically, I had the solution (`"h"` and `"l"` lines).